# "Dimension too large" with data computed and/or imported

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, dimensions

The problem is in several QA here but I didn't find this configuration that can help others.

My context : I compute data externally (in lua but the source of calculations doesn't mind). Then I create my pgf/Tikz plot with these data.

I then got "Dimension too large. I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet." even if my polynomial function was unlikely to create 1/0 problems !

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply to **reduce the number of decimals** input in pgf/Tikz.

I formatted the numbers I computed with something like string.format("0.3f",data) but I could also use some rounding prior the import in pgf/Tikz plot.

Hope this will help.